# Magento 2: Swatch image upload not working due to js error

Tags: magento2, php, swatches, magento2.1.6, configurable-swatches

I am working on magento 2 and when i try to upload a swatch attribute image but each time i get the below error. Please check the below screenshot.

[image]

I debug code more and found that image path error.

This is my js path : **vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/adminhtml/web/js**

```
iframeHandler = function () {
       var imageParams = $.parseJSON($(this).contents().find('body').html()),
       fullMediaUrl = imageParams['swatch_path'] + imageParams['file_path'];
```

**imageParams['file_path']** value is undefined.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for your issue.

It cause is the role of admin  .. Please change `ADMIN_RESOURCE` from  `Magento_Swatches::iframe` to `Magento_Backend::admin` in file `Magento\Swatches\Controller\Adminhtml\Iframe\Show`

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with uploading swatch image, but only on custom roles users. For admin user there is no issue.
Pham thanh is in the right direction, but I think there is a better way, by just adding the missing acl in a custom modue. It has been fixed already in magento 2.2 (https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/68a79d980dce923bcb361a18ee28e3bf6ea42f86)

If you can't upgrade to 2.2 you can create a module and just add the missing acl :

/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/acl.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_attributes">
                        <resource id="Magento_Swatches::iframe" title="Swatches" translate="title" sortOrder="70" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was due to using PHP 7.1. It's a Magento bug which ash been documented here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11828, also you can see the fix here https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/ee5fc2ece394318aa8f06ecaaae15ffc6dddb645

I hope it helps.